# How to set the Maximum Path Length with CMAKE?

Tags: cmake

How can I set the Maximum Path Length in a variable with CMAKE?

I know how I can get it from my computer:

```
cabellos@ozzy:~$ getconf PATH_MAX /
4096
cabellos@ozzy:~$ getconf NAME_MAX /
255
```

But this only will work on linux, isn't?

Comment: `CMAKE_OBJECT_PATH_MAX` May be of some help have a look on http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake2.6docs.html#variable:CMAKE_OBJECT_PATH_MAX

Comment: You can execute the shell commands in cmake using `execute_process` and `add_custom_command`

Comment: @bikram990 this variable is empty. From the docs "This variable may be set to specify the limit explicitly."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the comments, I solved tiwh the next code:

```
if(CMAKE_HOST_UNIX)
  execute_process( COMMAND getconf PATH_MAX / 
    OUTPUT_VARIABLE OBJECT_PATH_MAX OUTPUT_STRIP_TRAILING_WHITESPACE)
  execute_process( COMMAND getconf NAME_MAX / 
    OUTPUT_VARIABLE OBJECT_NAME_MAX OUTPUT_STRIP_TRAILING_WHITESPACE)
else()
  set(OBJECT_PATH_MAX 260)
  set(OBJECT_NAME_MAX 255)
endif()
```

Comment: The correct name of the variable is [CMAKE_OBJECT_PATH_MAX](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_OBJECT_PATH_MAX.html), with `CMAKE_` prefix.