# Maximum path lengths with CMake

Tags: windows, cmake, path

I have a project that uses CMake and builds inside a deeply nested set of directories on Windows and typically fails due to excessive path lengths.

Based on this answer - [How to set the Maximum Path Length with CMAKE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15617484/how-to-set-the-maximum-path-length-with-cmake) - (and on the comment from @Tsyvarev below - [Maximum path lengths with CMake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68351713/maximum-path-lengths-with-cmake#comment120800960_68351713) - I put this inside the CMakeLists.txt in the project root and close to the top of the file (i.e. before any other processing):

```
set(CMAKE_OBJECT_PATH_MAX 250)
set(CMAKE_OBJECT_NAME_MAX 245)
```

(As the build is always on Windows I did not bother with the Unix test in the answer in the earlier question.)

However, it still fails.

I have other mechanisms to shorten the path lengths so I know this is the issue here - but I'm looking for general advice to give to users about how they can set up their CMake builds to ensure they avoid this problem - my understanding was that CMake would use a hashing scheme to avoid the long path names but that doesn't seem to be happening.

So does such a mechanism exist and how do I access it if it does?

Comment: The correct name of the variable is [CMAKE_OBJECT_PATH_MAX](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_OBJECT_PATH_MAX.html), with `CMAKE_` prefix.

Comment: Thanks for that - but still not working as I expected unfortunately

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can set the path length limit in CMake with `CMAKE_OBJECT_PATH_MAX`, for example:

```
if (WIN32)
  set(CMAKE_OBJECT_PATH_MAX 260)
endif ()
```

But really if you have the power to do so, you should just remove the path length limit (from Windows 10 v1607 onward) via the PowerShell command:

```
New-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem" `
-Name "LongPathsEnabled" -Value 1 -PropertyType DWORD -Force
```

See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/maximum-file-path-limitation?tabs=powershell

Comment: But what does setting the limit do?

Comment: It shortens the length of CMake's generated object file path names. If the base binary directory plus the target's output name is too long for your file system, that's just a bad configuration. [Docs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_OBJECT_PATH_MAX.html). In some cases, setting `CMAKE_*_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY` can help, too, as long as there aren't name clashes. [Docs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.21/manual/cmake-variables.7.html?highlight=OUTPUT_DIRECTORY#variables-that-control-the-build)